# Get class of a clicked image and modify corresponding form field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck with this task:

I have a function attached with onclick="myFunction(this);" to tens of images of my page.
Inside the function I retrieve the class name of the clicked image.
Lastly I would like to look inside a html form and modify an input field with the same id as the retrieved class.

Here is an example to clarify:

1. User clicks on image with class="green"
2. We find the input field of a form with the id="green" and change it's value to 1

or

1. User clicks on image with class="red"
2. We find the input field of a form with the id=red" and change it's value to 1

and so on..

I have most of the code but what I dont seem to get is how I should use the retrieved class of an image to find a corresponding id in the form.

Comment: If you put up your existing code, people can help you more exactly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can concatenate the class name with `#` sign and select the input tag:

```
 var clas = $(this).attr('class') // if image has only 1 class 
 $('#' + clas).val('1')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, and I assume you are since you tagged the question "jquery", you don't want an `onclick=...`, you want to assign the handlers with jQuery:

```
$("img").click(function() {
    $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).val("1");
    // or
    $("#" + this.className).val("1");
});
```

But with your existing `myFunction()` you can do this:

```
function myFunction(el) {
    var matchingInput = document.getElementById(el.className);
    if (matchingInput)
        matchingInput.value = "1";
}
```

Your concept of "look inside a html form" doesn't really apply if the element you are looking for has an id, because (if your html is valid) there will be only one element with any given id so you can get a reference to that element directly with `document.getElementById()` or the jQuery/CSS selector equivalent `$("#someid")`.

Note that using the `class` attribute for this purpose makes it impossible to assign other classes to the same img elements, so I'd suggest you instead use a `data-xxx` attribute:

```
<img data-relatedFieldId="field1" class="someclass1 someclass2" src="...">
```

And then in your function:

```
$("#" + $(this).attr("data-relatedFieldId")).val("1");
```

Comment: Don't you mean `$(this).data("relatedFieldId")`?

Comment: @mplungjan - Nope. I never use `.data()` to retrieve attributes because I don't like its built-in data conversion, but yes: in this case it would do the same thing. (I use `.data("key")` only to retrieve values previously set with `.data("key",val)`, not attributes.)